# Laravel5.2 default auth check if user is verified in database before login and display custom message

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel5.2 auth and I have added an additional field : verified(y/n) in users table. Now before login I want to check if user is verified(Y) in database and if not verified display a message that your account is not yet verified.

Answer (score 1):

If method `authenticated` exists in the `AuthController` it will be called from Laravel trait `AuthenticatesUser`. Use this method to block the user if it is not verified yet and, if required, resend the email.

```
    public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if (!$user->activated) {
        $this->activationService->sendActivationMail($user);
        auth()->logout();
        return back()->with('warning', 'You need to verify your account. We have sent you an activation code, please check your email.');
    }
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth` you will find `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php` there you define what you want to do with your login.

Comment: I did following inAuthenticatesUsers.php

It is working. It checks if user is verified or not. But, How can I display custom message to user that verification is not done. As of now it is displaying default authentication error "Record doesn't exist with us"

`     $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);
  $credentials['verified']='Y';  
        if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials,$request->has('remember'))) {
            return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
        } `

Comment: \Session::flash('message', "some text.");
Check session::get and session::flash or send ->with your message

Comment: or read whole file that i point you on there is function
 protected function getFailedLoginMessage()
 {
  return 'These credentials do not match our records.';
 }